# Angular view did not get update after the value is change within subscribe function

Tags: angular, typescript

i like update commentInfo variable based on data that get from api, after subscribe function below i get the data but when i change the commentInfo variable and want it to show in view i did not work

```
import { Component, Input, NgZone } from '@angular/core';
import { CommentService } from './comment.service';

interface CommentInfo {
  by: string;
  id: number;
  parent: number;
  text: string;
  time: number;
  type: string;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-comment',
  templateUrl: '<div class="comment-wrapper">  
        <div class="comment-desc">
          {{commentInfo?.text}}
        </div>

        <div class="comment-time">
          <div class="comment-desc">
              {{commentInfo.time}}
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>',
  styleUrls: ['./comment.component.scss'],
})
export class CommentComponent {
  @Input() commentId = 0;

  loadingComment = false;
  commentInfo : CommentInfo | undefined;

  constructor(
    private storyCommentService: CommentService,
  ) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {        
      this.loadingComment = true;
        this.storyCommentService.getComment(this.commentId).subscribe((data) => {
            console.log(data) ->> data is exist but it wont change commentInfo below
            this.commentInfo= data as CommentInfo;
      })    
      this.loadingComment = false;

  }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure there aren't any runtime errors on the page? If you are calling `conmmentnfo.time` and `commentInfo` starts as undefined, it will throw an error in the JS console. You'd want to guard that by using `commentInfo?.time` in your layout instead.

Comment: You might want to add an `async` pipe to your template binding.  Try changing it to `{{commentInfo?.text | async}}`.  If you make a stackblitz I'll tinker with it to see if I can find the problem.